# node is always ""waiting for localhost" in browser

Tags: express, ejs

I have a simple RESTAPI crud application, where posts and commments should be submitted to the nodeJS routes. Everything works as it should only that it says: "Waiting for localhost" forever in the browser when I click one of the form buttons.
Could this be due to event propagation in the html/ejs?. Thanks in advance!

app.js:

```js
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var express = require("express");
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

let myDB = [{ post: "hello", comment: "hello1" }];

//Read
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index.ejs", { posts: myDB });
});

//Create
app.post("/addPost", function(req, res) {
  let newComment = { post: req.body.createP, comment: req.body.createC };
  myDB.push(newComment);
});

//Update
app.put("/updatePost", function(req, res) {
  let index = Number(req.body.updateI) - 1;
  // res.send("you have reached the update route " + index);
  let updatedComment = { post: req.body.updateP, comment: req.body.updateC };

  myDB.splice(index, 0, updatedComment);
});

//Delete
app.delete("/deletePost", (req, res) => {
  //res.send("you have reached the delete route " + req.body.del);
  let index = Number(req.body.updateI) - 1;
  myDB.splice(index, 1);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("server is running");
});
```

index.ejs:

```html
<h1>Index page</h1>

<P>Read posts</P>
<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>

<li><%=post.post %></li>
<li><%=post.comment %></li>

<%})%>

<P>Create post</P>

<form action="/addPost" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="post" name="createP" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="comment" name="createC" />
  <button>Create a new post</button>
</form>

<P>Update post</P>

<form action="/updatePost?_method=PUT" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="updateI" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="post" name="updateP" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="comment" name="updateC" />
  <button>Create a new post</button>
</form>

<P>Delete post</P>

<form action="/deletePost?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="sequence number" name="delI" />
  <button>Delete a post</button>
</form>

<form action="http://localhost:3000/">
  <input type="submit" value="Refresh" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are very new to API development. You are not sending any response back to browser after performing some DB operation. So browser waits for a response until request timeout. after each form submission, you should send response something like this:

```
app.post("/addPost", function(req, res) {
  // application logic goes here
  // once done send response as below
  res.render("index.ejs", { posts: updatedPosts });
})
```

Also, learn ajax request vs form action `submit`

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful answer, it solved my issue. So as I understand, each request to the node server has to be followed by a response to the browser. There are no one-way requests?

Comment: @vytasK, there is a lot to say but this would be helpful to your curiosity voyage https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_http.asp